# SQL Profiler Templates Missing - additional repair steps?

Tags: sql-server-profiler

I have the issue where SQL Profiler Templates are not being found, I am using an install of SQL Server Profiler 10.0.1600.22, and I am connecting to 2008 R2 remotely.

So I am aware of the "fix" whereby you can copy the templates folder from 100 to 1050 in the same directory. ie. http://www.mattbutton.com/2011/06/01/sql-profiler-templates-missing/

But this is still not showing my templates in SQL Server Profiler.

What additional steps can I take to restore the default templates?

Do I need to copy the templates from the Machine SQL Server is installed on to my computer?

Comment: Did you try push restart after copying to 1050?

Comment: In the end I had to uninstall SQL Server 2008 and INSTALL SQL Server 2008 R2. Everything works as it should and I could find NO remedy for the original question.

Comment: As long as it is working properly now, that's all it matters. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder "trick" only works if you have the higher version installed and you are trying to connect to a lower one. Profiler v.110 will not look for v.120 folder, just like version 100 (SQL Server 2008) will not look for anything above itself (it has no way of knowing that there might be a template or two in the future 1050 folder).

Once you've installed the 2008 R2 version, everything falls in place.

The image attached is showing you how the valid situation should look like - version in the file path is the highest one:

[image]